# How to convert UTC time to local time using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert UTC time to local time by giving country code using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data){
console.log("mmm",data.country);
});
```

I will get country code from this code(data.country).Let 04:36 is my UTC time.Then to convert this time to local time depending on the value in data.country

Comment: What country code are you getting ? Is it an integer please share few examples.

Comment: i get like "IN" for India, "OM" for Oman,......@PrabodhM

Comment: Can you print your `data` object in the question, with all the key values. It will be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: Object :                                                                                                               city: "Delhi"                                                                                        country: "IN"  , ip: "14.195.227.206"  ,                                                             loc: "28.6667,77.2167"   ,                                                                           org: "AS55441 TTSL-ISP DIVISION" ,                                                          region: "National Capital Territory of Delhi"

Comment: In that case when you have no timezone string, you will need to get a reference map for country code with timezone string and then using that get the correct timezone date.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working when i implement timezone .@PrabodhM

Comment: So your code is working now ? Cheers !